# guessing particular solution of a recurrence equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Please I need help on this recurrence equation .. I have tried googling but couldn't find much on this...

The recurrence equation  is $a_n - 2a_{n-1}  = (n+1)  2^n $

I can find the homogenous solution but need help with the particular.
I know if it is just $2^n$, I'll try guessing  $A2^n$  and if it is $n$,  I can guess $An + B$ .

1) How do I guess $n+1$? Will  it be $An + B + C$?

2) What can I guess for the particular solution above?

Answer (score 0):

Because $2^n$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation, and the right side is 
a polynomial of degree $1$ times $2^n$, you should look for a particular solution that is (a polynomial of degree $2$ with no constant term)  times $2^n$, i.e. 
$$ a_n = (A n^2 + B n ) 2^n$$